# inner query where-clause dependent on outer query attribute

Tags: sql, sql-server

Given these three tables:

*Student(sID, sName)*; 
   *Course(cID, cName)*; and *Studies(sID, cID)*.

*Studies* contains three tuples with the same sID and different cID's, that is one student studying three different courses.

I'm trying to do the following query:

```
select s.sID, s.sName
from Student s
where 'sID1' in
      (select st.sID
       from Studies st
       where st.sID = s.sID);
```

To my knowledge, when running the query, all three tuples should be printed. However only one tuple is printed. So far I've come to the conclusion that this is because of the where-clause `where st.sID = s.sID` in the inner query but I'm having trouble understanding the logic behind it. Is it because the clause is dependent on the outer query? Why is only one tuple printed and not all three?

Comment: Please paste the tables and the required output

Comment: Learn the `joint` syntax and stay away from `in` as much as you can.

Comment: @ajeh why are you suggesting to avoid using IN? It certainly doesn't seem like the way to go about things here but that is a strange blanket statement to make.

Comment: Sometimes `in` optimizes into a `union`. `join` never does.

Comment: @ajeh that isn't explaining you statement about avoiding IN. It is entirely too vague to provide details. Do you have a reference that explains what you are trying to say?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case the 'IN' clause checks whether the SId of student Table present in studies table . It doesn't mean the query should return multiple result set if there are mutiple matches in the subquery.  Since there is only one student the query returns one record.

IN clause is used to check or to make sure the select list should return only those values mentioned in the IN condition.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know your requirements, but what you wrote is way more readable using below syntax:

```
select s.sID, s.sName
from Student s
inner join Studies st on st.sID = s.sID
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query should return a tuple only because   sID1  is related to a single Student ..

```
 where 'sID1' in
  (select st.sID
   from Studies st
   where st.sID = s.sID);
```

in subquery also if you select more that a value for sID1 this is resolved by the in clause  like a single result

the `in`  clause is a set operator